# Why my v-for does not work properly, displays one number and not several as it should

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, axios

Why my v-for does not work properly, displays one number and not several as it should. The task consists of what you need to do pagination and in order to display all pages from 1 to n pages I need to know their number, I kind of made the property to be cleared, but when I insert it into html in the v-for loop, only 1 is shown.

My html:

```
<span v-for="n in evenPosts" :key="n.id">{{ n }} </span>
```

My Vue js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {

    return{
      counter: 1,
      zero: 0,
      posts: [],
      createTitle: '',
      createBody: '',
      visiblePostID: '',

    }
  },

  watch: {
      counter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          this.getData()
      }
  },
  created(){
      this.getData()
   },

   computed: {
     evenPosts: function(){
       return Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10)
     }
   },
methods: {
      getData() {
          axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=10`).then(response => {
              this.posts = response.data
          })
      },
    }
```

There are a total of 98 posts in my API, so the pages should not be 1 but 10, since there are 10 posts on one page

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TTJD.png)

Comment: Because `eventPosts` only returns a single number. Check your computed statement.

Comment: I understand this, but how to fix it?

Comment: Can you return the length of the post directly instead of dividing it by 10. What does it output if you do that?

Comment: this.posts.length is the number of all posts, 10 the number of posts on one page, and when we divide thios.posts.length divided by the number of posts on one page we will know the number of pages we need

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is, your computed property is returning a number. 
As you can see in this screenshot 
[image]

I don't really know what you were trying to achieve with that computed property, but if you iterate for example over posts, it will work.
Of course you will need to parse and do stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the limit on the axios call to 10. This means that you are getting 10 posts and not 98 and you only have one page.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusx6aLh/3/) for a request limit of 100.

```
axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${this.counter}+${this.zero}&_limit=100`).then(response => {
          this.posts = response.data
      })
```

Comment: What you suggested doesn't make sense, and even if you were right,  you can still iterate through 10 items.

Comment: You can, if you have 10 items to iterate. But as the OP is dividing it by 10 it only has 1 item, which he's iterating over.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti I believe the OP wants to display page numbers for pagination. The computed prop is intended to return the **number** of pages with a page size of 10 posts. He's using the [`v-for` syntax to render a range of numbers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range), so if there were 100 posts, the computed property would return 10, and the `v-for` would render `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti As @Radu points out, the OP's request URL incorrectly includes a low response limit (i.e., `_limit=10`), causing only 10 results to be returned from the API, and thus only 1 page. The solution is to bump up the limit (or remove it).